# Function receive char array as parameter and return char array

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

I'm trying to make a "Truco" game and it's in the beginning but I don't have much experience with the C language.

I'm trying to make a function that receives an array of char (string) and returns another array of char.

I receive the following error when I compile my code:

```
276 [Warning] passing arg 1 of `retornaMaior' from incompatible pointer type
```

Here's relevant part of the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// const

char cartas_jogo[] = "4567QJKA23";
char naipes_jogo[] = "ZCEO";

int retornaIndice(char carta)
{
    int a = 0;
    int retorno = 0;
    for (a=0; a<strlen(cartas_jogo); a++)
    {
        if (carta==cartas_jogo[a])
        {
            retorno = a;
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}

char *retornaMaior(char *cartas, const char carta_comp)
{
    int posCartaComp = retornaIndice(carta_comp);
    int a = 0;
    int posMaior = 0;
    int tem = 0;
    int posA = 0;
    for (a=0; a<6; a+=2)
    {
        int posCarta = retornaIndice(cartas[a]);
        if (tem == 0)
        {
            if (posCarta>posCartaComp)
            {
                posMaior = posCarta;
                posA = a;
                tem = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (posCarta<posMaior)
            {
                if (posCarta>posCartaComp)
                {
                    posMaior = posCarta;
                    posA = a;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    char *carta = "YY";
    carta[0] = cartas_jogo[posMaior];
    a++;
    carta[1] = cartas[posA];
    return carta;
}

int main()
{
    char carta_jogada[3];
    printf("\n\nDigite uma de suas cartas para jogar: ");
    scanf("%s", &carta_jogada);

    // conferir length carta jogada
    // conferir se tem carta jogada
    char mesa_jog1[] = {'Y','Y','\0'};
    mesa_jog1[0] = carta_jogada[0];
    mesa_jog1[1] = carta_jogada[1];

    char jog2_carta1[] = {'Q','C','\0'};

    char cartas[7];
    cartas[0] = jog2_carta1[0];
    cartas[1] = jog2_carta1[1];
    cartas[2] = jog2_carta2[0];
    cartas[3] = jog2_carta2[1];
    cartas[4] = jog2_carta3[0];
    cartas[5] = jog2_carta3[1];
    cartas[6] = '\0';

    printf("%s", retornaMaior(&cartas,mesa_jog1[0]));
    getch();
}
```

This is a really short part of the code but I think that's enough for you guys help me out.

Comment: Loose the `&` in the call to `retornaMaior(&cartas,mesa_jog1[0])` It should be `retornaMaior(cartas,mesa_jog1[0])`

Comment: When I do it the compiler shows no errors but it stops to work when I enter a value...

Comment: note that `cartsas` where there is heap memory assigned in main is NOT the same as `char *carta='YY';` and the several lines following. You are assigning to a string literal then trying to return that. There is your bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of problems:

```
demo.c:68:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[3]’ [-Wformat]
demo.c:81:17: error: ‘jog2_carta2’ undeclared (first use in this function)
demo.c:81:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
demo.c:83:17: error: ‘jog2_carta3’ undeclared (first use in this function)
demo.c:87:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘retornaMaior’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
demo.c:26:7: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[7]’
```

And more ...

```
char *carta = "YY";
carta[0] = cartas_jogo[posMaior];  /* Error: carta is a string literal (read only) */
a++;
carta[1] = cartas[posA]; /* Error: carta is a string literal (read only) */
return carta;
```

Finally:

```
printf("%s", retornaMaior(&cartas,mesa_jog1[0]));
```

should be

```
printf("%s", retornaMaior(cartas,mesa_jog1[0]));
```

because `cartas` is (decays into) a pointer

Comment: Ok, but how can I solve this kind of problems like

expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[7]’

Comment: You solve this using `retornaMaior(cartas,...` note `cartas` without `&`